# a2enable:command not found on Ubutntu terminal with Tomcat Server in EC2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04

I need to do this on Ubuntu LTS 12.04

```
a2enable  sana.default
 a2enable sana.default.ssl
```

But on entering a2enable I am  getting the error
I have installed both Apache tomcat in my server 
On Entering this

```
a2enable  sana.default
```

I am getting

```
a2enable:command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is `a2ensite`. Give that a try.